# xbindkeys works only few times or at least once

Tags: linux, logitech-mouse, events, button-remapping, xbindkeys

I have enabled reaction on thumb button of my MX Master under Debian 8 with xbindkeys. 
My configuration is:

```
# the Alt+Left is receive as distinct event.
"gnome-terminal"
    m:0xc + c:23
    Control+Alt + Alt_L
```

You can follow this on [this very good explanation.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1574075#p1574075) 

My problem now is that this event is recognized and fired but only once or only sometimes.

To investigate fopr errors I tried to start in verbose mode:

```
xbindkeys -n -v                                                                           Fr 11. Dez 01:59:09 CET 2015
displayName = :0
rc file = /home/xxx/.xbindkeysrc
rc guile file = /home/xxx/.xbindkeysrc.scm
getting rc guile file /home/xxx/.xbindkeysrc.scm.
WARNING : /home/xxx/.xbindkeysrc.scm not found or reading not allowed.
1 keys in /home/xxx/.xbindkeysrc

min_keycode=8     max_keycode=255 (ie: know keycodes)
"gnome-terminal"
    m:0xc + c:23
    Control+Alt + Tab
starting loop...
Key press !
e.xkey.keycode=23
e.xkey.state=12
"gnome-terminal"
    m:0xc + c:23
    Control+Alt + Tab
got screen 0 for window 9e
Start program with fork+exec call
Key release !
e.xkey.keycode=23
e.xkey.state=12
```

As you can see it seems to be valid. `.scm` warning can be ignored, if added it will behave the same.
I tried to monitor all logs but without success, there is nothing happening.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok got it working. 
In Gnome there is **Ctrl+Alt+Tab** combination which interrupts the event from xbindkeys. I changed it to **Ctrl+Super+Tab** so xbindkeys works now.
I will leave this question and answer so maybe it will help someone.